# What is the purpose of the group argument in sample.split?

Tags: r, split

I've been reading over [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caTools/versions/1.17.1/topics/sample.split) of `sample.split` in the CaTools package and I am struggling to think of any practical reason to use the `group` argument. Are there any areas where it has seen practical use? In my attempts to experiment with it myself, I couldn't even find a good reason to type out a vector that was the same length as my data set.

Comment: Can you please check if the below solution helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we go through the example in the `?sample.split`, with the 'group', it samples as a block and without using group, it is different.  According to `?sample.split`

> group - Optional vector/list used when multiple copies of each sample are present. In such a case group contains unique sample labels, marking all copies of the same sample with the same label, and the function tries to place all copies in either train or test subset. If provided than has to have the same length as Y.

```
library(MASS)
library(caTools)
data(cats)   # load cats data
Y <- cats[,1] # extract labels from the data
msk1 <- sample.split(Y, SplitRatio=3/4)


g <- rep(seq(length(Y)/4), each=4); g[48]=12;
msk2 <- sample.split(Y, SplitRatio=3/4, group=g)
```

---

Comment: That doesn't do anything to show me why it would be used in practice. In fact, I'm more confused than ever. The effect of this code seems to be that it generates a list of length equal to that of the row of data in question, divides it in to blocks of four, and randomly calls 1/4 of them all FALSE and the rest TRUE. Assuming that I'm right, I can't see at all how that matches up to what the documentation is describing. For example, despite what the docs say about Sample, this result didn't care that the data was a set that only contained 'F' repeated many times and 'M' repeated many more.

Comment: @J.Mini  If you check the 'msk1' , 'msk2', the 'msk2' TRUE/FALSE are repeated for the entire group, while in 'msk1' it is not the case because it is doing with `SplitRatio` on the entire vector

Comment: I'm aware, but I fail to see the use of this or how it corresponds to what the documentation says.

Comment: @J.Mini  Check this example `v1 <- 1:20;
g1 <- rep(1:4, each = 5);  sample.split(v1, SplitRatio =1/2);sample.split(v1, SplitRatio =1/2, group = g1)` here the TRUE/FALSE extends for the entire group

Comment: The practical reason is that when you want to do a group by sample split.  Usually, we do this with `group_by` in dplyr, but here, it is not needed

Comment: Grouping by sample split is a good enough practical example for me to be satisfied, but I admit that I'm still struggling to see how the effect of your code matches up to what the documentation for the Groups argument describes.

Comment: @J.Mini the documentation is correct that it will place a whole group of elements in training or test rather than some elements sampled.  i.e. if a group have 10 elements, all of them will go either training or test.  and not 50%  or 60% goes to either one of them